# addToRear method for Singly linked list

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I am not sure if I am going about this the correct way, I simply want to implement the addToRear method in my Singly Linked List(generic for now), just have had mixed advice, so a little help? (Is this the correct way to implement the addToRear Method?)

```
 public void addToRear(T element) {
    T end = new T(newElement);
    if (head == null) 
         {head = end;} 

    }
```

Comment: is this the correct way to implement the addToRear method...

Comment: it's not adding to the rear, so I'd say no.

Comment: What if the head is not null?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..
 You create a Node type, that contain your Generic element..

```
public void addToRear(T element) {
    Node end = new Node(element);
    if (head == null){
        head = end;
    } else {
        Node temp = head;
        while(temp.next != null){
             temp = temp.next;
        }
        temp.next = end;
    }

}
```

Comment: So how i do?? or what i do?

Comment: it really is not homework. Look at my other questions on here, do they look like I'm begging for hw answers? I ask when I genuinely don't  understand.